# Buffered Emailing Logger for .Net (preferably a NLog Target)?

Tags: c#, email, logging, nlog

Could anyone point me to a NLog target or some other logging sink that would allow sinking logs to SMTP but in a buffered fashion (multiple errors logged in a single email)?

Anyone who's ever used a SMTP sink has likely been spammed sometime or another from the default SMTP logging sinks :) Hoping someone can point me to an existing solution so i don't have to figure out all the myraid headaches inherent with doing this well and reliably at the level of a well tested sink :P Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [BufferingWrapper](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/BufferingWrapper-target) target.

> A target that buffers log events and sends them in batches to the wrapped target.

You can use it in combination with the [Mail](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Mail-target) target.

```
<target
    xsi:type="BufferingWrapper"
    name="mail_buffered"
    bufferSize="5">

        <target
            xsi:type="Mail" ... >
            ...
        </target>
</target>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! So now i just need to confirm if the mail target is nice enough to send a single email for multiple log events being dumped into it. From what i remember reading of the source, it doesn't :)